# How to correctly backpropagate in a fully connected Neural Network?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to write a neural network from scratch and It seems that I have misunderstood something or done something wrong because my model is not performing as well as it should. Can someone help me see the error of my ways?

These are the activation functions and loss function that I use.

```
def mse(y: np.ndarray,  y_pred: np.ndarray, derivative=False) -> np.ndarray:
    """Returns the mean square error between to vectors"""
    return  2*np.subtract(y_pred, y) if derivative else np.square(np.subtract(y_pred, y))

def sigmoid(x: np.ndarray, derivative=False) -> np.ndarray:
    return  sigmoid(x) * (1. - sigmoid(x)) if derivative else 1. / (1. + np.exp(-x))
    
def relu(x: np.ndarray, derivative=False) -> np.ndarray:
    if ~derivative:
        return np.maximum(0, x)
    x[x<=0] = 0
    x[x>0] = 1
    return x
```

And this is my implementation of a Neural Network that creates a fully connected network with layers_size that is something like this [input, x,x,x, output ]

```
@dataclass
class NN(Model):
    layer_sizes: Tuple[int]
    activation_functions: List[Callable]
    
    def random_initializers(self) -> None:
        """Make a random start for weights and bias"""
        
        self.num_layers = len(self.layer_sizes)-1
        
        self.parameters = {f"W{i+1}": np.random.randn(self.layer_sizes[i+1], self.layer_sizes[i]) * np.sqrt(1. / self.layer_sizes[i+1]) 
                       for i in range(self.num_layers)}
        
            
    def forward(self, X: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        self.parameters['A0'] = X
        
        for i in range(self.num_layers):
            self.parameters[f"Z{i+1}"] = np.dot(self.parameters[f"W{i+1}"], self.parameters[f"A{i}"])
            self.parameters[f"A{i+1}"] = self.activation_functions[i](self.parameters[f"Z{i+1}"])
            
        return self.parameters[f"A{i+1}"]

    def backward(self, loss_prime):
        update = {}

        # Calculate W update
        error = self.activation_functions[self.num_layers - 1](loss_prime, derivative=True)
        for i in range(self.num_layers)[:0:-1]:
            update[f"W{i+1}"] = np.dot(error, self.parameters[f"A{i+1}"])
            error = np.multiply( np.dot(self.parameters[f"W{i+1}"].T, error), self.activation_functions[i-1](self.parameters[f"Z{i}"], derivative=True))

        return update
        
    def update_weights(self, update: dict[str,np.ndarray]) -> None:
        """Updates the weights of the model after one step or epoch."""
        for key, value in update.items():
            for w_arr in self.parameters[key]:
                w_arr -= self.learning_rate * value
            
    
    def fit(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray ) -> None:
        """trains the model using the vector features X and labels Y."""
        self.hist={"loss":[0], "frame":[]}
        # random start
        self.random_initializers()
        for epoch in tqdm(range(self.epochs)):
            loss= 0
            # for each sample in training set feed-forward and backpropagate
            for i, x in enumerate(X):
                # feed-forward
                pred = self.forward(x)
                # add loss 
                loss+= self.loss(pred, y[i])
                error = self.loss(pred, y[i], derivative=True)
                # compute gradient update
                update = self.backward(error)
                # update weights
                self.update_weights(update)
```

The loss changes in the first couple of epochs but then stops changing after that.

Comment: If I am reading your code correctly, your units seem to have no bias parameter?

Comment: Also, you should always validate your gradient computations numerically, as explained e.g. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHMzNW8Agq4).

Comment: What I've understand from testing is that the dim of numpy arrays not properly fixed with creates some wrong shapes